# Adding PRIMARY KEY: Table contains duplicated values

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, primary-key, plpgsql, postgresql-8.4

In PostgreSQL 8.4.13 I have 2 tables and a procedure to fill the 2nd table:

```
    create table pref_users (
            id varchar(32) primary key,
            first_name varchar(64),
            last_name varchar(64),
            female boolean,
            avatar varchar(128),
            city varchar(64),
            login timestamp default current_timestamp,
            logout timestamp,
            last_ip inet,
            vip timestamp,
            mail varchar(256)
    );

    create table pref_rep (
            rep_id serial,
            id varchar(32) references pref_users(id) check (id <> author) on delete cascade,
            author varchar(32) references pref_users(id) on delete cascade,
            author_ip inet,
            good boolean,
            fair boolean,
            nice boolean,
            about varchar(256),
            stamp timestamp default current_timestamp
            /* primary key(id, author) */
    );

   create or replace function pref_update_rep(_id varchar,
            _author varchar, _author_ip inet,
            _good boolean, _fair boolean, _nice boolean,
            _about varchar) returns void as $BODY$
            begin

            delete from pref_rep
            where id = _id and
            age(stamp) < interval '1 hour' and
            (author_ip & '255.255.255.0'::inet) =
            (_author_ip & '255.255.255.0'::inet);

            update pref_rep set
                author    = _author,
                author_ip = _author_ip,
                good      = _good,
                fair      = _fair,
                nice      = _nice,
                about     = _about,
                stamp     = current_timestamp
            where id = _id and author = _author;

            if not found then
                    insert into pref_rep(id, author, author_ip, good, fair, nice, about)
                    values (_id, _author, _author_ip, _good, _fair, _nice, _about);
            end if;
            end;
    $BODY$ language plpgsql;
```

The `pref_users` table holds generic information about users.

The `pref_rep` holds comments (column `about`) about users (column `id`) created by another users (column `author`).

For the 2nd table I have forgotten to declare the [primary key](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/ddl-constraints.html) pair (that line is commented above).

I'm trying to add that primary key at the psql prompt, but it fails - probably because for some reasons (I don't know how could it happen with my procedure above?) I have few records where same `author` comments same `id` on several occasions:

```
# alter table pref_rep add primary key(id, author);
NOTICE:  ALTER TABLE / ADD PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "pref_rep_pkey" for table "pref_rep"
ERROR:  could not create unique index "pref_rep_pkey"
DETAIL:  Table contains duplicated values.
```

My question is how to find those duplicated pairs of `id` and `author`?

I've tried:

```
# select id, count(id) from pref_rep group by id order by count desc limit 5;
       id       | count
----------------+-------
 OK408547485023 |   706
 OK261593357402 |   582
 DE11198        |   561
 DE13041        |   560
 OK347613386893 |   556
(5 rows)
```

but that of course doesn't give me the pairs...

**UPDATE:** Catcall's suggestion (thank you!) gives me 190 such duplicated pairs:

```
           id           |         author         | count
------------------------+------------------------+-------
 DE10598                | OK495480409724         |     2
 DE12188                | MR17925810634439466500 |     3
 DE13529                | OK471161192902         |     2
 DE13963                | OK434087948702         |     2
 DE14037                | DE7692                 |     2
......
 VK45132921             | DE3544                 |     2
 VK6152782              | OK261593357402         |     2
 VK72883921             | OK506067284178         |     2
(190 rows)
```

but actually my real question is how to delete the older (by the `stamp` column) of the duplicates? I've tried many queries at the psql prompt unsuccessfully...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What bout this query (also on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/59fbc/11))?

```sql
DELETE FROM pref_rep p USING (
  SELECT id, author, max(stamp) stamp
    FROM pref_rep
   GROUP BY id, author
  HAVING count(1) > 1) AS f
WHERE p.id=f.id AND p.author=f.author AND p.stamp<f.stamp;
```

---

Check [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html) on `count()` function.

You can specify any expression. `1` means that all rows will be counted, 'cos `1` is never `NULL`. Same effect if you use `count(*)`. I prefer the latter in fact, not sure why I used `count(1)` this time :)

Comment: Awesome and I didn't know about SQL Fiddle yet :-)

The only thing I still don't unserstand is: `count(1)`

Answer (score 2):

This should identify the duplicates.

```
select id, author 
from pref_rep
group by id, author
having count(id) > 1
```

You might also have to look at NULLs, too, because both those columns allow NULL.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have a hint please, how to delete the older (by the column "stamp") of the 190 duplicated pairs?